# Simpson rule integration,Python

Tags: python, integral, simpsons-rule

I wrote this code,but I not sure if it is right.In Simpson rule there is condition that it has to has even number of intervals.I dont know how to imprint this condition into my code.

```
def simpson(data):
    data = np.array(data)
    a = min(range(len(data)))
    b = max(range(len(data)))
    n = len(data)
    h = (b-a)/n
    for i in range(1,n, 2):
        result += 4*data[i]*h
    for i in range(2,n-1, 2):
        result += 2*data[i]*h
    return result * h /3
```

Comment: lower limit of integration

Comment: you should trying printing Min, range, len.  One of those seem to be a variable of type List rather than a function

Comment: Did you mean `min()`? The builtin for getting the smallest integer from a collection?

Comment: Yes,of course you are right

Comment: this `a = min(range(len(data)))` gives always `a = 0` and this `b = max(range(len(data)))` gives always `b = len(data)-1` - maybe you try to do something different.

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly enough, you can find it in the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Python):

```
from __future__ import division  # Python 2 compatibility

def simpson(f, a, b, n):
    """Approximates the definite integral of f from a to b by the
    composite Simpson's rule, using n subintervals (with n even)"""

    if n % 2:
        raise ValueError("n must be even (received n=%d)" % n)

    h = (b - a) / n
    s = f(a) + f(b)

    for i in range(1, n, 2):
        s += 4 * f(a + i * h)
    for i in range(2, n-1, 2):
        s += 2 * f(a + i * h)

    return s * h / 3
```

where you use it as:

```
simpson(lambda x:x**4, 0.0, 10.0, 100000)
```

---

Note how it bypasses your parity problem by requiring a function and `n`.

In case you need it for a list of values, though, then after adapting the code (which should be easy), I suggest you also raise a `ValueError` in case its length is not even.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already seem to be using numpy you may also consider using scipy which conveniently provides a Simpson's rule integration routine.

```
from scipy.integrate import simps
result=simps(data)
```

See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.html for the full documentation (where they discuss the handling of even/odd intervals)